# Conditional text in a text box depending on drop down box values

Tags: text, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm having all sorts of fun trying to get a text box to display a message depending on the contents of two dropdown selection boxes.
I have a small list of messages I would like displayed depending on what the dropdown box contents are eg.If dropdown box 1 (contained in cell N7) had ON selected AND dropdown box 2 (in cell N8) was also ON then a message contained in cell AA25 would populate the message box. Similarly, if N7=yes and N8=no then the text contents of AA26 would show up instead.
If none of the conditions are true then I need a blank box (necessary) or even a random text from a list of inspirational quotes!! (Not entirely necessary but it would be fun!!)
I know how to link a message box to a cell content but each time I try to use boolean it tells me I'm missing something! I tried some of the examples listed on other folk's questions to no avail.
Here's my somewhat simple code when I try to use boolean..

=IF $N$7="ON" AND $N$8="ON" THEN $AA$25       Very basic as you can see but I like simple!!

I get a range reference or defined name error.. as you can tell, I'm new to this but learning slowly. Any help would be appreciated. Eventually there will be several IF/AND/OR statements in the conditions with different text for each result.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this for some kind of spreadsheet?  If so, which one?

Comment: It's an Excel spreadsheet.